# Structuring many-to-many/bidirectional references with C++ smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I decided to do a project in C++, because I didn't know C++ yet. I'm trying to do everything in C++ as much as possible, meaning very few raw pointers.

I'm running into trouble with how to structure my collection of objects. Fair warning, this description is going to be very abstracted.

- There is exactly one instance of a class. Let's call it `Foo`
- This `Foo` needs to hold many objects of class `Bar`. Requires fast insertion and deletion and does not require order, so I want to use a set.
- Each `Bar` owns exactly 4 objects of type `Baz`, which are created and fixed on initialization.
- Each `Baz` has pointers to many other objects of type `Baz`. Each `Baz` must also have a reference to the `Bar` that owns it, for implementation reasons.
- Given an existing `Baz` object, I need to remove the corresponding `Bar` object from `Foo`'s set and free memory accordingly. (I have an algorithmic guarantee that on removal, `Baz` objects for the owning `Bar` only point to other `Baz` objects owned by that `Bar`)

The way I tried to implement it is by storing a set of unique Bar pointers for Foo, shared pointers to handle many-to-many Baz relationships, and plain references for the Baz->Bar relationship, 4 per Bar object. The problem is that I no longer have a way to get the Bar `unique_ptr` from the `Baz` object. I have a reference but the set removal method expects a `unique_ptr`, thus no easy removal. Is there a better way to structure this that doesn't have to resort to manual pointer/memory management?

Comment: I just want to clarify, by "set", do you mean `std::unordered_set`? The reason I ask is because there is also `std::set`.

Comment: Yes, I mean unordered set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I don't see the need for smart pointers here because all the objects are already managed by containers - so their deletion is assured.

So I would just use raw pointers and let the containers do their job:

```
struct Baz
{
    struct Bar& bar;
    std::vector<Baz*> bazs; // no need to be smart - deleted elsewhere
    Baz(Bar& bar): bar(bar) {} // don't use bar in this constructor!
};

struct Bar
{
    std::array<Baz, 4> bazs;
    Bar(): bazs({*this, *this, *this, *this}) {}
};

struct Foo
{
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
};
```

There is nothing wrong with using raw pointers as long as the objects they point to are managed either by a smart pointer or a container.

I used `std::vector` for this example but use whatever you feel appropriate. I suspect `std::vectors` may compete with `std::set` because they use contiguous memory which plays well with CPU cashing.

Comment: Right, I think I was just being dumb (there's no reason for ``Foo`` to store pointers to ``Bar`` objects when it could just store the ``Bar`` objects themselves.) And then when you do it that way, references are good enough for pretty much everything. Thanks!